# Al guardar en un arreglo de objetos me sale el error 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: c#

En c# al momento de guardar en un arreglo de objetos me sale el error `System.NullReferenceException` al guardar en `data.Perso[u].Nombre = item.Nombre;`

El código es:

```
                var victi = db.TBL_PERSONAS.Where(x => x.Fk_Carpeta ==Datos.ID_CARPETA).ToList();
                V_Carpetas data = new V_Carpetas();                    

                int u = 0;
                foreach (var item in victi)
                {
                    data.Perso[u].Nombre = item.Nombre;
                    data.Perso[u].Edad = item.Edad;
                    u++;
                }
```

Comment: donde inicializas la propiedad `Perso`? deberías mostrar la definición de la clase del objeto `data` sino, imposible ayudarte

Comment: Muestra el código de la clase `V_Carpetas`lo mas probable es que no estes inicializando coorectamente `.Perso`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la clase `V_Carpetas` asegurate que estes inicializando `.Perso` con una `List` y no con un array ya que no sabes cuantos elementos añadirás luego a la lista.

Ejemplo

```
public class V_Carpetas
{
    public List<Persona> Perso = new List<Persona>();
}
```

Luego cuando vayas a añadir elementos desde `victi` hacía `.Perso` utiliza el método `.Add` de la clase `List<T>` para añadir elementos a `.Person`

Ejemplo

```
foreach (var item in victi)
{
    data.Perso.Add(new Persona
    {
        Nombre = item.Nombre,
        Edad = item.Edad
    });
}
```

Comment: eso solucionó mi problema

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta puedesa marcarla como aceptada